# $3^k \cdot (n + \frac12) - \frac12$ powers of $2$

Tags: number-theory

Does the above sequence $3^k (n + 1/2) - 1/2$ always have a power of 2 in it for all n and some k?

Let $s_{nk} = 3^k (n + \frac12) - \frac12$, does $s_{nk} == 2^m$ for some m and k.

I'm thinking that because 3 is coprime with 2 that the sequence will eventually hit a power of 2 but it is a hunch and I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: Are you fixing $n$ and looking at $a_k=3^k(n+1/2)-1/2$ or fixing $k$ and looking at $a_n=3^k(n+1/2)-1/2$? I can't quite tell from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation reduces to

$$3^k(2n+1)=2^m+1$$

for some $k,n,m$.

If you're fixing $k$, take $m=3^{k-1}$. Then, by Lifting the Exponent Lemma (you can find a description and proof of the lemma along with notation [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/lifting-the-exponent/)),

$$\nu_3\left(2^{3^{k-1}}+1\right)=\nu_3\left(2+1\right)+\nu_3\left(3^{k-1}\right)=k,$$

so

$$3^k\big|2^{3^{k-1}}+1\implies \frac{2^{3^{k-1}}+1}{3^k}=2n+1$$

for some $n$. So, fixing $k$, there always exists a pair $(m,n)$ for which $3^k(2n+1)=2^m+1$.

If you're fixing $n$, take $n=3$. We have that the left hand side is a multiple of $7$, while

$$2^m+1\in\{2,3,5\}\bmod 7,$$

so there are no integers $K$ for which

$$\frac{2^m+1}{2n+1}=K,$$

and certainly no powers of $3$.

Comment: I am looking for the statement to hold for each n and some k and m. Basically any arbitrary positive integer(an odd integer works) n, their exists some k and m such that the stated relationship holds. So, given n(not fixed, but for every positive integer), does the equation $3^k(2n+1) - 2^m - 1 = 0$ have an positive integral solution $(k,m)$? Using the language of lifting: Given some arbitrary $n$, their exists a $k$ s.t. $v_p(3^k(n + 1/2) - 1/2) = 0$ for all $p > 2$

Comment: @AbstractDissonance Thanks. My example of $n=3$ in the second half of the answer should show that, for some $n$ ($n=3$ but probably others as well), there do not exist any $k,m$.

Comment: The ‘$v_3(2^3+1)$’ should be ‘$v_3(2+1)$’.

Comment: @Szeto You're right; I've fixed it.

Comment: Carl, would you mind to look at my answer? My impression is that there is no $k$ that *for all* $n$ the evaluation of $s_{nk}$ has powers $2^m$ with $m>0$.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I see no reason that shouldn't be true; my answer only claims that for all $k$, there exists a pair $(m,n)$ so that $2^m+1=(2n+1)3^k$, not that for some $k$, all $n$ will do.

Comment: Ah, I see. I took that *"... always have a power of 2 in it for all n and some k?"* from the OP as *"... for some k  always have -for all n- a power of 2 in it?"* Perhaps this is an overinterpretation of the OP.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I think OP was asking about whether the sequence always has a power of $2$ in it for fixed $n$ as $k$ varies, but it's hard to say for sure. Either way, I think one of our answers covers it.

Answer (score 0):

$$ s_{nk}=3^k \cdot (n+ \frac12) - \frac12 \\
s_{nk}=3^k n + { 3^k-1\over 2} \\
$$

- For even $k$ we need even $n$ to have some power of $2$ in $s_{nk}$
- For odd $k$ we need odd $n$  to have some power of $2$ in $s_{nk}$